# Instrumental test for Realm database gives "Call 'Realm.init(Context)' before creating Realmconfiguration" even though I call it

Tags: android, android-studio, testing, realm

For my Android application I use the Realm mobile database. I want to write tests for this, and the best way I found of testing was using instrumental tests.

This is the constructor of my database class:

```
public Database(Context context) {
    this.context = context.getApplicationContext();

    Realm.init(context);

    RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .name("com.arnowouter.badger.realmdatabase") // TODO: 4/10/2016 check if encryptable
            .build();

    realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfig);
}
```

As you can see, Realm.init(context) is called. But when I run this test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@MediumTest
public class DatabaseTest {

    Database database;
    Context context;

    @Before
    public void setupDatabase() {
        context = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();
        database = new Database(context);
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Call `Realm.init(Context)` before creating a RealmConfiguration
        at io.realm.RealmConfiguration$Builder.<init>(RealmConfiguration.java:399)
        at io.realm.RealmConfiguration$Builder.<init>(RealmConfiguration.java:394)
        at com.arnowouter.badger.Database.Database.<init>(Database.java:38)
        at com.arnowouter.badger.DatabaseTest.setupDatabase(DatabaseTest.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
        at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
        at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1970)
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering the fact that the Context stored in Realm is the application configuration like this

```
// Thread pool for all async operations (Query & transaction)
volatile static Context applicationContext;
```

Which is initialized like this

```
public static synchronized void init(Context context) {
    if (BaseRealm.applicationContext == null) {
        if (context == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Non-null context required.");
        }
        RealmCore.loadLibrary(context);
        //...
        BaseRealm.applicationContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

This means that the `context` you give it returns `null` for `context.getApplicationContext()`.

Unfortunately, apparently the instrumentation's context returns `null` for `getFilesDir()`, so we need to obtain an application or an activity context.

I'd probably just set application in a static variable, and use that.

```
public class CustomApplication extends Application {
    private static CustomApplication INSTANCE;

    public static CustomApplication get() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        if(INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = this;
        }
    }
}
```

And in manifest:

```
<application name=".CustomApplication"
```

That way you can do:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@MediumTest
public class DatabaseTest {

    Database database;
    Context context;

    @Before
    public void setupDatabase() {
        Realm.init(CustomApplication.get());
        context = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();
        database = new Database(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works! Thanks! Next problem Is that I can't open a realm because I have no read-write permissions when running my instrumentation test...

Comment: io.realm.exceptions.RealmFileException: Unable to open a realm at path '/com.arnowouter.badger.realmdatabase.management'. Please use a path where your app has read-write permissions. in /Users/cm/Realm/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_SharedRealm.cpp line 81 Kind: PERMISSION_DENIED.

Comment: That path doesn't sound like you're trying to open it in the `/data` folder (internal storage). Do you specify the directory anywhere? If not, the instrumentation context returns something stupid.

Comment: No, the in the realm configuration, I only give it a name

Comment: Can you please verify what `Context testContext = new TestContextWrapper(context); testContext.getFilesDir()` returns? What is `testContext.getFilesDir()`, is it `null`?

Comment: It is null indeed.

Comment: Modified my answer accordingly. Please check if it helps. No, the `static` variable to `Application` isn't a problem, because application exists throughout the life of the app itself.

Comment: Seems like a big change just for the purpose of testing, no? And I don't extend Application

Comment: Well you can put together `/data/data/packagename/` if you want manually, but I don't consider that to be simpler or more reliable. I'd probably just call `Realm.init(Context)` from the Activity itself, some form of BaseActivity.

Comment: The issue here is that you can't seem to obtain the internal storage directory through the instrumentation context.

Comment: @WouterVanderSchraelen any luck?

Comment: We just have to give it a context that returns a context for `getApplicationContext()` which returns the valid internal storage path for this particular application. I'm surprised it's such a hassle -  this means this wouldn't have worked via the instrumentation context even if the init call wasn't needed.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I have a similar structure as OP's code-base but I am trying to run them under `test` i.e they are not instrumented tests and I keep getting the error to do `Realm.init()` which I have as in [this](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/unitTestExample/src/test/java/io/realm/examples/unittesting/ExampleActivityTest.java) example

Comment: Realm doesn't support JVM outside Android yet.